# fatal error 'GL/glx.h' file not found on mac after Xquartz is installed

Tags: macos, x11

When i run the program i get the following error

fatal error: 'Gl/glx.h' file not found

I am attempting to run a c++ xll graphics program on my mac. I have already downloaded Xquartz and used it to run multiple graphics programs on my computer and now i am trying to figure out what i'm missing in order to get this program to run. if anybody can point me in the right direction it would be wonderful!

Thanks

here is a copy of the make file provided

```
  1 ## If you receive XRR errors, include -lXrandr option on LFLAGS line
  2 all: atrace
  3 ##LIB    = ./libggfonts.so
  4 LIB    = ./libggfonts.a
  5 LFLAGS = -lX11 -lGLU -lGL -lm #-lXrandr
  6 CFLAGS = -O2 -Wall -Wextra
  7 SOURCE = atrace.cpp init.cpp scene.cpp render.cpp sphere.cpp ppm.cpp      log.cpp \
  8 vector.cpp input.cpp files.cpp perlin.cpp texture.cpp divide.cpp \
  9 cubemap.cpp matrix.cpp fresnel.cpp haze.cpp animate.cpp \
  10 photons.cpp subsurf.cpp
  11 
  12 #all: atrace atrace.o init.o scene.o render.o sphere.o ppm.o log.o \
  13 #       vector.o input.o files.o perlin.o texture.o divide.o \
  14 #       cubemap.o matrix.o fresnel.o haze.o animate.o
  15 #
  16 #atrace: $(SOURCE) fonts.h defs.h ppm.h extern.h bvh.h animate.h $(LIB)
  17 #       g++ $(CFLAGS) $(SOURCE) $(LFLAGS) $(LIB) -o atrace
  18 
  19 atrace: atrace.o init.o scene.o render.o sphere.o ppm.o log.o \
  20 vector.o input.o files.o perlin.o texture.o divide.o \
  21 cubemap.o matrix.o fresnel.o haze.o animate.o photons.o subsurf.o \
  22 defs.h ppm.h extern.h bvh.h animate.h
  23         g++ atrace.o init.o scene.o render.o sphere.o ppm.o log.o vector.o \
  24 input.o files.o perlin.o texture.o divide.o cubemap.o matrix.o fresnel.o \
  25 haze.o animate.o photons.o subsurf.o $(LIB) -oatrace $(LFLAGS)
  26 
  27 
  28 atrace.o: atrace.cpp defs.h ppm.h extern.h bvh.h animate.h
  29         g++ atrace.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  30 init.o: init.cpp defs.h
  31         g++ init.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  32 scene.o: scene.cpp defs.h
  33         g++ scene.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  34 render.o: render.cpp defs.h
  35         g++ render.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  36 sphere.o: sphere.cpp defs.h
  37         g++ sphere.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  38 ppm.o: ppm.cpp defs.h ppm.h
  39         g++ ppm.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  40 log.o: log.cpp defs.h
  41         g++ log.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  42 vector.o: vector.cpp defs.h
  43         g++ vector.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  44 input.o: input.cpp defs.h
  45         g++ input.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  46 files.o: files.cpp defs.h files.h
  47         g++ files.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  48 perlin.o: perlin.cpp defs.h
  49         g++ perlin.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  50 texture.o: texture.cpp defs.h
  51         g++ texture.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  52 divide.o: divide.cpp defs.h bvh.h
  53         g++ divide.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  54 cubemap.o: cubemap.cpp defs.h
  55         g++ cubemap.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  56 matrix.o: matrix.cpp defs.h
  57         g++ matrix.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  58 fresnel.o: fresnel.cpp defs.h
  59         g++ fresnel.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  60 haze.o: haze.cpp defs.h
  61         g++ haze.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  62 animate.o: animate.cpp defs.h animate.h ppm.h
  63         g++ animate.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  64 photons.o: photons.cpp defs.h
  65         g++ photons.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  66 subsurf.o: subsurf.cpp defs.h
  67         g++ subsurf.cpp -c $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS)
  68 
  69 clean:
  70         rm -f atrace
  71         rm -f *.o
```

Updated Make file still getting 
fatal error 'GL/glx.h'

[picture of updated make file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V46WQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile with the option `-I/opt/X11/include` and link with the options `-L/opt/X11/lib -lGL -lX11`.

Comment: hey @kenthomases i was provided a really big make file and i'm not to sure where exactally i would add the -lGL -lX11 here is the make file can you spot anywhere i should add it will it be after the -C

Comment: You add the `-I...` option to `CFLAGS` and the `-L...` option at the beginning of `LFLAGS`.

Comment: i added -I and the -L to the CFLAGS and the LFLAGS and it still wont allow me to run this program. I was wondering if i put it in the wrong place possibly? i put it in at lines 5 & 6 would i have to but it there or should it be affter the $(CFLAGS) $(LFLAGS) on every g++ compile statement  Thanks!

Comment: First, don't use images to convey textual data. Put the actual contents of the edited makefile into your question. That said, you only added, literally, "-I" and "-L". You need to add the options as I wrote in my answer. In my previous comment, I used "..." just to avoid duplicating what I already wrote.

Comment: sorry about that i think that worked but theres one more problem i'm having i get the following error now clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &timestart); use of undefined identifier i read that this is not supported on MAC OS but do you know anything about this function?