# In C, how do I install GL/glx.h , GL/gl.h and GL/glu.h on Mac OS

Tags: c, macos, glu, glx

I have some code which includes the headers GL/glx.h , GL/gl.h and GL/glu.h . I do not even know what these are, and Google is not a lot of help because there is so much noise in the search results. So (optionally) what are they, but more importantly, how do I install them on a Mac (Mac OS 10.15.4). I have installed other stuff using homebrew so that would be my preference.

EDIT: By renaming the headers to OpenGL/glx.h etc, I can now find gl.h abd glu.h but not glx.h.

This answer [openGL glx.h missing form xcode 4 mac lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516637/opengl-glx-h-missing-form-xcode-4-mac-lion) says "If you install XQuartz you get X11 which has glx.h" but this is not correct, at least not for me. I have installed xquartz using brew, but still cannot find glx.h.

Another site suggested installing Xcode, which I did, but that does not contain glx.h either.

Comment: This is OpenGL and you can get it through Homebrew. Keep in mind that Apple has deprecated OpenGL support for macOS.

Comment: I could not find OpenGL on homebrew, but it appears to be there already. If I change the `#include` commands to `#include <OpenGL/glx.h>` etc, it still says it cannot find glx.h, and there is no glx.h file where I would expect it, i.e. in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers/`

Comment: Just to clarify, changing to OpenGL is some progress, because it can now find 2 out of 3 files: it finds gl.h and glu.h, presumably because they are in the dir I mention in the last comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing xquartz fixed it. OpenGL (at least the versions I found) is insufficient because it does not include `glx.h`. The page xquartz.org says, *"The XQuartz project is an open-source effort to develop a version of the X.Org X Window System that runs on OS X. Together with supporting libraries and applications, it forms the X11.app that Apple shipped with OS X versions 10.5 through 10.7."*

So I downloaded and installed xquartz, and then compiled with `-I/opt/X11/include` instead of `-I/usr/X11R6/include`, and linked with `-L/opt/X11/lib` instead of `-L/usr/X11R6/lib`; as suggested at [fatal error 'GL/glx.h' file not found on mac after Xquartz is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40186686/fatal-error-gl-glx-h-file-not-found-on-mac-after-xquartz-is-installed) ; and it all worked.