# Why is Glew not finding OpenGL headers in MacOS Catalina?

Tags: c++, opengl, macos-catalina, glew

Upgrading to Catalina has broken my build and three days of searching has not solved the problem.  The code worked fine pre-Catalina.

The specific error I'm getting is

```
/usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:1217:14: fatal error: 'OpenGL/glu.h' file not found
#    include <OpenGL/glu.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /usr/local/include/GL/glew.h:1217:14: 
note: did not find header 'glu.h' in
      framework 'OpenGL' (loaded from '/System/Library/Frameworks')
```

My glew is installed from brew, and brew info says:

```
$ brew info glew
glew: stable 2.2.0 (bottled), HEAD
OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library
https://glew.sourceforge.io/
Conflicts with:
  root (because root ships its own copy of glew)
/usr/local/Cellar/glew/2.2.0 (38 files, 3.4MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2020-10-27 at 10:52:58
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/glew.rb
License: BSD-3-Clause
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 6,917 (30 days), 12,565 (90 days), 50,126 (365 days)
install-on-request: 3,383 (30 days), 6,400 (90 days), 26,243 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

As far as I can tell, the part about "root ships its own copy of glew" isn't the case, because a find search of the entire system doesn't find another glew.h.

My build flags are (set via CMake)

```
SET(APP_COMPILE_FLAGS  "-g -Wall -Wno-nullability-completeness")
SET(APP_LINK_FLAGS     "-framework OpenGL -lglfw -lGLEW")
```

Other possibly relevant information:

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

I'm running XCode 12.0.1, Command tools for XCode 12, and MacOS 10.15.7.  Any insights?

Comment: Can you find the file `glu.h` on your system?

Comment: Yeah, sudo find /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools -name glu.h -print gives /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers/glu.h.  But just putting that as an include directory doesn't help, because Glew is expecting "OpenGL/glu.h"

Comment: `Headers/glu.h` is not `OpenGL/glu.h`. Can you also find a header `glu.h` in the directory `OpenGL`?

Comment: Right.  But doing surgery on Glew's headers doesn't seem like the answer.

Comment: Why are you just looking in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`? Have you installed `glu.h`? It seems that `glu.h` doesn't come with `glew`.

Comment: No.  The only other glu.h on the system is buried inside XCode: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers/glu.h
I think the MacOS framework stuff is supposed to magically perform the indirection, but it's not working for whatever reason.

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62586763/in-c-how-do-i-install-gl-glx-h-gl-gl-h-and-gl-glu-h-on-mac-os I think you have to install glu

Comment: No, his problem is different in that his system is finding OpenGL/glu.h, whereas mine is not.  OpenGL is supposed to be part of the system still, as evident by the fact that multiple instances of glu.h are physically present on the disk, but for some reason -framework OpenGL is not finding them.

Comment: Just for kicks, I tried manual surgery on glew.h to put in a hideous explicit path to the command line tools glu.h, but it just kicks the problem downstream: /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers/glu.h:8:10: fatal error: 
      'OpenGL/OpenGLAvailability.h' file not found
#include <OpenGL/OpenGLAvailability.h>
Apple's own header files expect <OpenGL/blah.h> but it's not working for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly isn't the ideal right answer, but creating a link

```
/usr/local/include/OpenGL -> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Headers
```

is a hack that solved my problem.